Bigquery - Get latest close notes
number     Created_Date      Closed_Date       Close_Notes
T1         8/10/2024          null              null    
T1         8/10/2024          8/11/2024         Completed Successfully
T2         8/11/2024          null              null    
T2         8/11/2024          8/13/2024         null
T2         8/11/2024          8/13/2024         Completed Successfully

It is time series data. We need output as below,
Expected output:
number     Created_Date      Closed_Date       Close_Notes
T1          8/10/2024        8/11/2024          Completed Successfully
T2          8/11/2024        8/13/2024          Completed Successfully

Query i tried,
SELECT
    Number,
    Close_Notes,
    min(Created_Date),
    max(Closed_Date)
  FROM
    SN_Change_Request group by Number


Simply WHERE Close_Notes = 'Completed Successfully'? Or WHERE Closed_Date IS NOT NULL?

The question here is: Can a number value (e.g T3) have more than one Closed_Date?

closed_date always have same value even though it has multiple entry. And Close_notes is free text field.

if closed_date always have same value even though it has multiple entry, how do you choose which row to return?

Add some more rows of sample data, incl. tricky multiple entry. (And adjust the expected result.)

I just need max of Close_date

What's the expected result if a T has several rows with the same max close_date? Or different start_date?

Created_Date and Closed_date will not have different value for a ticket

What about different close_notes?

You can use row_number() window function to get each number's row having the latest Close_Date:
select number, Created_Date, Closed_Date, Close_Notes
from
  (
   select t.*,
          row_number() over (partition by number order by Close_Date desc) rn
   from tablename t
) dt
where rn = 1

Note: will choose an arbitrary row if several rows have the same latest Close_Date. Use RANK() instead if you want all of them.
